# Have prestashop product combination quantity set to a default value

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm using prestashop 1.7.6 and have products with different combinations.

I need to set to a default value (ex: 12) the quantity of the various product combinations when i generate them, without having to typing them in manually.

Do you know if there's any way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With a script or directly in database with an ex query:

```
UPDATE PREFIX_stock_available SET quantity = 12;
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I created the products and combinations and then needed to set the default value. So perhaps you can follow this process after import instead of setting a default value. I am also assuming you have Stock Management turned on for all your products.

1. Import products and combinations using PrestaShop's CSV import.
2. Load the SQL database using a SQL tool (my host provides phpMyAdmin. I tried the built-in PrestaShop SQL, but it was broken). I connected using an external SQL manager and ran the following queries:
3. Run the query

   SELECT * FROM `psuo_stock_available`
4. Verify these are the quantities you want to update, or use more SQL language to narrow down the list to precisely what you want to update. For example, where quantity=0 would be one I can imagine you would use for newly imported products.
5. Run the UPDATE query to change the product's quantities to 12 on all SELECT(ed) rows aka product combinations.

```html
    UPDATE `psuo_stock_available` 
    SET
    quantity=12
```

Bonus: I also updated the Out of Stock behavior and the Depends on Stock behavior for each product and combination while I was editing the table.